# iOS save movie from camera to core data

Tags: ios, core-data, camera

In my app I would like to save a movie that has just been shot into core data. I don't want these movies to end up in the general camera roll. My idea was to get the clip and load it into an object 'movie' that I then could save to cor data. Much like a photo in addressbook. Core data let us save into External Record File, whatever that is.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    movie = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

But movie shows up nil when I go to save it.

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newMedia = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Media" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newMedia setValue:@"Video Clip " forKey:@"title"];
    [newMedia setValue:now forKey:@"date_time"];
    [newMedia setValue:movie forKey:@"movie"];
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the video like this :

```
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```

And save the `videoData` in  database ,in your case `movie` as long as it is `NSData` in type.

Your code :

```
movie = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

should get the `UIImage` from `imagePickerController` after you took a picture and if you say that you're recording then that's why  `movie = nil;`

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat! Now I just have to get it back from core data when I didSelectRow in the tableview and get to the detail view where I show shooting date and other stuff.

Comment: No problem , glad that I could help, if you have any other problems let me know.

Comment: @sorynogod - When I try to play the videoData it comes back null.   `- (IBAction)playVideoBtn:(id)sender {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self.media valueForKey:@"movie"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
    
    NSLog(@"play back video");
    NSLog(@"temp dataString: %@", dataString);
    NSLog(@"temp movie path: %@", movieURL);
    
    
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
`

Comment: You aren't doing it right, when you get the NSData you must save it in the database as BinaryData or to your NSDocuments Directory, because just having the URL doesn't help. And you must access the file saved to load the video into the MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: I'm saving it as Binary Data `[newMedia setValue:videoData forKey:@"movie"];` Just can't figure out how to load it into MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: well , you need to save it into NSDocumentsDirectory as myVideo.mov file and only save the URL into the sqlite database and just load that

Comment: So it's no good saving the video clip into the core data as Binary Data?

Comment: I'm not doing that because of performance issues so I recommend you save only the link to the documents directory there and save the video in the documents as well